# pyserial: No module named tools

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

I have installed the latest pySerial on my Ubuntu box with python 2.7.2, and it works fine for most things, but whenever I try to import the 'tools' package, it says that it can't find 'tools'. The [documentation for pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html?highlight=list#listing-ports) explicitly references this 'tools' package.

```
>>> from serial import tools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    import serial.tools
ImportError: No module named tools
```

and when I:

```
>>> serial.VERSION
'2.5'
```

which is the latest version according to [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyserial/)

So why can't I get to the 'tools' package of pySerial?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `pip` to install `pyserial`. First install pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

After that install `pyserial`:

```
sudo pip install pyserial
```

Comment: Presumably you meant for me to `sudo pip install pyserial --upgrade`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I tried everything before I saw this answer.

Comment: Is there any way to do this same thing but with windows? Thanks.

Comment: On OS X, you can use `sudo easy_install pip` to install pip. From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x

Comment: What is the explanation for why pip install pyserial installs the tools sub-module and apt-get install python-serial doesn't?

Answer (score 11):

You have to uninstall `serial` and `pyserial` then reinstall `pyserial`:

```
pip uninstall serial
pip uninstall pyserial

pip install pyserial
```

Because the both libs contain a file named `serial.py`, you get a name conflict.

Answer (score 7):

I got here because I had the same problem.
The strange thing was that

```
import serial
```

worked, but

```
from serial.tools import list_ports
```

didn't.

Turns out stupid me **named the script "serial.py". After renaming it everything worked**.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I installed `serial` but not `pyserial` after getting the  following error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'serial'
```

Then `import serial` was ok, but `from serial import tools` can't work.

Just `sudo pip uninstall serial` and `sudo pip install pyserial`

Hope to help people like me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ubuntu package does not quite match up with upstream.  compare the official pySerial package on their SVN:

http://pyserial.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyserial/trunk/pyserial/serial/

to the ubuntu package in launchpad:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/pyserial/raring/files/head:/serial/

Tools is missing there, too.  It does look like they keep the `miniterm.py` script, and install it... somewhere; I'm not versed enough in deb packaging to understand where, though.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on how I would go about uninstalling the ubuntu repo version and, in its place, installing the upstream sourceforge version?

Answer (score 1):

The pyserial-2.4-py2.7.egg in the site-packages folder was getting imported instead of from serial in the site-packages folder. Once I renamed this file so that it no longer imported from this it worked fine. You can easily debug this by doing

```
import serial
serial._ _path_ _
```

to see where serial is getting imported from.

Answer (score 0):

yes，use python-pip install ,,,then ,,,upgrade,,,the version of serial will be 2.7 ...it workes

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that doing "pip install --upgrade" doesn't work(as happened to me), in Linux you can check if you have a serial package in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, the new serial packaged the one that pip install goes to `/usr/**local**/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial`, for some reason the one in `usr/lib/python2.7/` has precedence and the module tools doesn't exist in that version of pyserial. Changing names or deleting the directory solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the difference between pip and python -m pip can be the version. for example, it may be that you call pip from python2, but when you type python -m pip then you get python3 and so on...

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the functions of module this way:

```
from serials import tools
```

For example: If I want to call `sqrt` function from `math` module, I would do:

```
from math import sqrt

import math.sqrt **is wrong.**
```

Comment: tools is not a function, it's a package, and can be imported as Sam is trying..  the package contains only modules and an empty `__init__.py`, so he'll have to import more to use anything, but it should never-the-less succeed without raising an exception, so long as the ubuntu package matches upstream (which it doesn't, see my answer)

Comment: Use pip to install pyserial. First install python pip: sudo apt-get install python-pip and then install pyserial: sudo pip pyserial

Answer (score -1):

From the pyserial webpage: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html

They recommend that you use the command:
python -m pip install pyserial

That worked for me. I don't know enough about pip to undersand the difference from just a regular pip install pyserial, but it worked for me (after much frustration).